# Memory-Efficient Element Handling in JSON Serialisation from Flux to S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, project-reactor

I am writing a large JSON array to S3 from a `Flux`. Collecting and serialising the entire stream of objects at once has substantial memory implications. This has led me to reinterpret this as a multi-part upload, with the code roughly resembling the following:

```java
results
    .map(this::serialize)
    .map(
         bytes ->
             uploadBytes(
                         bytes,
                         filename,
                         bucket,
                         index.getAndIncrement(),
                         uploadId))
```

This means that only a single element of `results` need be serialised in memory at any given time. This ostensibly works, but does not yield valid JSON, since the combined file is not comma separated or bounded with brackets.

We can add additional logic to check the index of the upload, so that the first element prepends a `[`, and every other element prepends a `,`. Giving the structure:

`[result1` + `,result2` + ... + `,resultX` + ...

Which might be determined by the following code:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
if (index == 1) {
    output.write('[');
} else {
    output.write(',');
}
output.write(bytes);
```

This strategy still omits the final bracket, since we do not know whether the current element is the final element. There is also a minimum size on S3 file parts of 5mb. The worst case would be finally uploading `]` padded with 5mb of whitespace.

Is there an idiomatic way to determine whether any given element in a `Flux` is the last, and that a complete signal directly follows?

Comment: You can capture the last element using `last` operator. Or you can use `doOnComplete`. Are you writing the elements sequentially?

Comment: @RahulKushwaha This was indeed another way this could have been performed. In an earlier iteration, I zipped the stream with itself, subscribing to last in one of them. Although this had the desired effect, it was messy, and therefore I opted for the solution described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, I simply wrote something to the effect of:

```java
results
    .map(this::serialize)
    .concatWithValues((byte) ']')
```

And then uploaded these to S3 in buffers of 5MB (rather than per element). Elements could thus be serialised lazily as the 5MB buffer is filled.